# Name ' outcome' is not defined - Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a rock, paper, scissors, game that I am running and when I reach the part where I will display the result in a new window, a NameError occurs saying name 'outcome' is not defined.

```
def game():

ai_choice = {'0':'Rock', '1':'Paper', '2': 'Scissors'}
def rock():
    ai = ai_choice[str(random.randint(0,2))]
    if ai == "Rock":
       output = "Tie"
    elif ai == "Scissors":
        output = "User Win"
    else:
        output = "User Lose"
    outcome.config(text = output)
    output_window()
def paper():
    ai = ai_choice[str(random.randint(0,2))]
    if ai == "Rock":
       output = "User Lose"
    elif ai == "Scissors":
        output = "Tie"
    else:
        output = "User Win"
    outcome.config(text = output)
    output_window()
def scissors():
    ai = ai_choice[str(random.randint(0,2))]
    if ai == "Paper":
       output = "Tie"
    elif ai == "Scissors":
        output = "User Lose"
    else:
        output = "User Win"
    outcome.config(text = output)
    output_window()

def output_window():
    global outcome
    show_output = Tk()
    show_output.title("Result")
    show_output.geometry("200x200")
    outcome = Label(show_output, text ='')
    outcome.pack()
```

Comment: Where are you getting outcome??

Comment: Ask yourself when `outcome` is defined and when the error occurs.

Comment: My outcome variable is inside the output_window function. The error occurs whenever I press a button on the main GUI to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, "output" is a local variable. This would mean that the other methods don't have access to it. I would recommend making output a global variable and using the global keyword whenever you need to set it. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Disregard this, got what you were asking confused.